# Using ClearNLP Semantic Role Labeler

Tags: java, parsing, nlp, semantics

I want to use clearNLP (http://clearnlp.wikispaces.com/) for extracting semantic role labels of an input sentence. I followed the instructions here: http://clearnlp.wikispaces.com/installation (I downloaded the jar files, put them in a directory called ClearNLP and set the classpath) but when I run the command `java com.clearnlp.run.Version`, I face the error: `Could Not find or Load Main`.

I tried it twice: Once I set the classpath as an environment variable of windows and ran the command in CMD. But, when it didn't work, I tried to create a java project, set the libraries using NetBeans and run the program. But, it didn't work, too.

BTW, when I run `echo %classpath%` command, I see that the classpath is set correctly.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try Eclipse.  I included the jars in a new project I created.  I then created a simple class like so

```
package test;

import com.clearnlp.run.Version;

public class TestClearNLP {

   public static void main String(args[]) {
      Version.main(args);
   }

}
```

When run, this creates output in the console of:

```
ClearNLP version 2.0.2
Webpage: clearnlp.com
Owner  : Jinho D. Choi
Contact: support@clearnlp.com
```

The only weird situation I ran into was that Eclipse did not like the jar files beginning with a period.  I removed those from my project and ran with the remaining libraries.